# How to solve recurrence relation $u_0=0, u_{n+1}=u_n+2n+1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

I know the explicit form for $u_0=0, u_{n+1}=u_n+2n+1$ is $u_n=n^2$ but I want to know if there is a generalized or formal way of finding the explicit term for this kind of sequences.

The answer seems to be some kind of “guessing” followed by an induction proof to validate the choice of the explicit formula, but there is no easy way to do so (apart from arithmetic-geometric sequences).

Note: WolframAlpha seems to [solve them](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%280%29%3D0%2C%20u%28n%2B1%29%3Du%28n%29%2B2n%2B1), I wonder how it does.

Comment: A straight forward way would be using generating function. You can also find the homogen-particular solution, since you recurrence is linear. The particular part is also guessing though, but guessing with obvious function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, given initial condition $u_0$ to the recurrence
$$u_{n+1}=u_n+a_n$$
with $a_n$ being an arbitrary sequence, we see that
$$u_{k+1}-u_k=a_k$$
so that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(u_{k+1}-u_{k})=u_{n+1}-u_0$$
is the same as $\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k,$
thus $$u_n=u_0+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k.$$
Use $u_0=0$ and $a_k=2k+1$ so that 
$$\begin{align}
u_n&=0+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k+1)\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1)\\
&=2\cdot\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n\\
&=n^2.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Telescoping to 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}(u_{k+1}-u_{k})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

**Another way:**

Let $U_n=An^2+Bn+C$, then $$A(n+1)^2+B(n+1)+C-(An^2+Bn+C)=2n+1 \implies An^2+2An+A+Bn+B+C-An^2-Bn-C=2n+1,$$ We get $2An+A+B=2n+1 \implies A=1, B=0$. Then $U_n=n^2+C$, using $U_0=0$, we get $U_n=n^2$.

Comment: How do we know $U_n=An^2+Bn+C$?

Comment: Because $U_{n+1}$ and $U_n$ need to be quadratic so that the difference is a linear functio namely $2n+1$.

Comment: How do you introduce the $A_n^2$ in the first place?

Comment: The succesive difference $U_{n+1}-U_n$ is linear $(2n+1)$ So $U_n$ has to be quadratic and the general quadratic is $An^2+Bn+C$, in the ens we get $A=1, b=0,C=0$

Comment: It has to be quadratic: how do you prove so?

Comment: $\Delta= U_{n+1}-U_n$, If $\Delta$ is zero $U_n$ is constant.  if $\Delta$ is linear function of $n$, then $U_n$ is quadratic, if $\Delta$ is quadratic, then $U_n$ is cubic, so on and so so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Generating functions. Having $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}u_nx^n=\sum_{n\geq 1}u_{n-1}x^n+2\sum_{n\geq 1}nx^n-\sum_{n\geq 1}x^n$, then we can see that $f(x)=xf(x)+2x/(1-x)^2-1/(1-x)$, or after some algebra $f(x)=x(x+1)/(1-x)^3$. Now using for example partial fractions decomposition we can find out 
$$
u_n=[x^n]f(x)=[x^n]\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}\right)\\=1-3(n+1)+2(n+1)(n+2)/2=n^2.
$$
To figure out sums such as $\sum nx^n$, notice that $$\sum_{n\geq 1}nx^n=x\sum_{n\geq 1}nx^{n-1}=x\sum_{n\geq 1}(x^n)'=x(1/(1-x))'=x/(1-x)^2,$$
and similarly the other way for $1/(1-x)^2$ and $1/(1-x)^3$.

Anyway in my opinion, in this case it seems easier to just guess the solution and then prove it (for example by induction), or methods shown in other answers (such as telescoping).